# Changing toolbar button text on menu item selection EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with a toolbar  as given below

```
{
    xtype: 'tbbutton',
    text: 'Button',
    menu: [{
    text: 'Better'
    },{
        text: 'Good'
    },{
        text: 'Best'
    }]
}
```

I want to write handler such that when I choose 'Good' the button text should change from 'Button' to 'Good'

I am able to access text property in the handler

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples:

Either you can give the toolbar button an ID

```
....
xtype: 'tbbutton',
id: 'mytoolbarbutton',
text: 'Button',
....
```

and access the button using

```
var button = Ext.getCmp('mytoolbarbutton');
```

Or you can create the button like this and add it to the toolbar afterwards:

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Button',
    menu: [{
    text: 'Better'
    },{
        text: 'Good'
    },{
        text: 'Best'
    }]
});

myToolbar.add(button);
```

This way you have a handle to the button even though it is added to the toolbar.

Comment: `Ext.get(...)` doesn't work here. See http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-elements-and-components/ for more details.